# jquery is thorwing error stating "idleTimeout is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsp and when it loads it's throwing `$(...).idleTimeout is not a function` in the console and for this rest of the scripts are not working in that jsp. I have included the jquery and scripts in my jsp as below :

I have tried to include different versions of jquery , but that didn't work either.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/NBO/assets/js/manageRoles.js${asset_id}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/NBO/assets/js/manageGuestUserMain.js${asset_id}"></script>
<link href="/NBO/assets/css/updateCredentials.css${asset_id}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/NBO/assets/css/manageRoles.css${asset_id}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Where in the https://api.jquery.com/ do you see the idleTimeout method?

Comment: @Taplar  I have not included the idleTimeOut method at all in my script.

Comment: @Taplar I think he's saying he never wrote that call at all, so nothing led him to believe it was a jQuery method.

Comment: The stack trace in the debugger should tell you where this call is happening.

Comment: Quick google, there is at least one plugin for idleTimeout.  https://github.com/JillElaine/jquery-idleTimeout/blob/master/README.md   One of the scripts may be dependent upon it, or another plugin that defines that method.  Very hard to tell with the question as it is.

Comment: I assume the error is originating from one of the `/NBO/assets/js` files.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason for the error. It's because the JSP was importing the jquery through  , and the JSP was defined the in spring tiles view name and the tiles was extending a default definition which had some jquery already. Since there were multiple jquery import , it was failing. I simply commented the jquery import in my JSP i.e.  and it worked smooth.